# Disabling git colors only when I log in from certain terminals

Tags: git, terminal, colors, disable, terminfo

## Question

I want `git` to automatically colorize the output when it is going to a device that can handle color and not colorize it when it cannot. How would one do this?

### Background

I sometimes develop code for older machines using the machines themselves. Some of them can handle ANSI color and some of them cannot. On UNIX systems we used to have a database called **TERMINFO** which listed capabilities of each terminal. It was easy to tell if a terminal supported color by checking the `colors` capability. If it was -1, then a program should definitely not send ANSI color sequences.

```
$ tput colors
-1
```

Ideally, git would use **TERMINFO** to automatically detect if ANSI color sequences are appropriate. But it doesn't and checks only `isatty()`. I suspect it is not a high priority for the git developers to add **TERMINFO** support, so I'm looking for any workaround that will give the same functionality.

I already know how to disable git color using `git config` and that is not what I'm asking. I want it to only be disabled when I log in from a terminal that does not support ANSI colors, such as a Digital VT340.

I also have already seen the `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'color.ui=never'"` environment variable, but according to @bk2204 and @torek, that variable is going to disappear soon.

Comment: I saw, on the mailing list, that someone was looking into using terminfo from Git. Not sure what *status* that had. Note that the thing that's going away is the `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` knob, not the `color.ui` knob, but manually tweaking the `color.ui` knob every time you log in might be annoying. You can probably automatically tweak it.

Comment: Thanks, @torek, I sure hope git someday is able to use terminfo. `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` may be a kludge, but git does not seem to provide any other way to set parameters per _process_ rather than per user.

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1: a shell function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ `tput colors` -lt 2 ]; then
    git() {command git -c color.ui=never "$@"; }
fi
```

The disadvantage is it cannot be used in shell scripts. I.e. if you run a shell script `git` will try to use colors anyway. So Variant 2: a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ `tput colors` -ge 2 ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/git "$@"
else
    exec /usr/bin/git -c color.ui=never "$@"
fi
```

Name the script `git`, make it executable and put in a directory that precede `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`. For example I have `PATH` that starts with `$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:…`; I put personal scripts into `$HOME/bin` and system-wide scripts into `/usr/local/bin`

To make things simpler you could name the script something like `gitc`, remove `/usr/bin/` and train your fingers to type `gitc` instead of `git`. Then you can put the script anywhere.

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't quite work. `if TERM=vt100 tput colors; then echo yup; fi` prints "-1" and "yup". Also, wouldn't an alias be cleaner? Maybe something like `[[ $(tput colors) -le 0 ]] && alias git="git -c color.ui=never"`

Comment: @hackerb9 Shell aliases and shell functions do not propagate to subprocesses, i.e. shell scripts.

Comment: (I mean, an alias would be simpler than Option 1, a shell function. Of course, if one were scripting `git`, one would still need to use Option 2, a shell script, )

Comment: Looks like `tput colors` just prints the `Co#` / `colors` numeric value, which is -1 when unset, so you need to test the output rather than the status. (Oddly, on my FreeBSD box, I can't get it not to claim 80. I wonder if it's using columns instead of colors...? Aha, yes, it is: `tput Co` prints the `Co#` value.)